# How to move project from TFS to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I'm looking for help on how to move a project from Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) with TFS over to GitHub?

I'm new to Git/GitHub but I want to get more familiar with it. I've got a personal project that I've been working on and have been using Team Services with TFS. I've installed the GitHub plug in for my Visual Studio and was able to log in and create a Repo on GitHub as well as a local Repo. I then went to the Advanced Settings of Source Control in VS and removed the bindings to the TFS server. I don't know what do do next?

Is it even possible to move over or would it be best to just make a copy of my local site and then create a whole new project connected to GitHub and then copy over the code?

Comment: Just updating. I ended up deciding to use VSO with Git. I made a copy of my code and then followed this article and basically started from scratch. Once I got up and running I copied my code over and did a commit/push.

Answer (score 2):

Github has a [Github importer](https://import.github.com/new).
It can take any git, Hg, and TFS repository and make it into a git repo for you.
There's also a project made to convert locally called [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs).

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'm having issues with it trying to log in to my TFS site but that's probably due to a network setting at work. I'm wondering if I can copy the code from my local TFS working folder to my local Git Repo and then see if I can get it pushed to GitHub.